# Type not in scope, but the required library is being imported

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have to work with the following Template Haskell code:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module myModule where

import Language.Haskell.TH

newtype C a = C (TExpQ a)
unC :: C a -> TExpQ a
unC (C x) = x
```

However when I load the file I get an error:

Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘TExpQ’

```
Perhaps you meant one of these:

  ‘TExp’ (imported from Language.Haskell.TH),

  ‘ExpQ’ (imported from Language.Haskell.TH)
```

I looked in the docs and TExpQ is in the library that should be loaded
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.16.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Lib.html

Is the library not loading? Is that why the type is not in scope?

Comment: Consider writing explicitly _what_ you import from a module. `import Language.Haskell.TH (TExpQ)` would have given a clearer error message.

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviations are defined in the [`Language.Haskell.TH.Lib` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.16.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Lib.html) of the [**`template-haskell`** package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell), so you should use:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module MyModule where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Lib

newtype C a = C (TExpQ a)

unC :: C a -> TExpQ a
unC (C x) = x
```

A module starts with an **U**ppercase, so `module MyModule`, not `module myModule`.

Comment: I see. I thought Language.Haskell.TH would have also imported the Lib. Thanks

Comment: @pmichaels: no, there is no "hierarchy" that importing `A` will import `A.B`, that would also result in a lot of trouble if one would `import Data`, since then there will be a lot of modules that sometimes export types with the same name. Some modules indeed re-export other modules.